UltraSearch found deleted files, how do I recover them?
UltraSearch has found two pdf files I was looking for. Unfortunately, both have been deleted from the Recycle Bin. Fortunately, UltraSearch reads their contents just fine and displays them in the preview window; it also correctly displays their sizes.
The path that it displays starts with C:\$Recycle.Bin\. When I right-click their names and click Restore, literally nothing happens. When I try dragging and dropping them somewhere, a message is displayed, stating that the file has not been found and it's probably no longer in the location (the location given is Recycle Bin). It'd be so convenient to have a handy option to save the files but it's not present. Not even right-clicking at the pages in the preview gives this option, although rotating pages is available.
Windows File Recovery at first didn't recover anything from that drive; the second time I run it, it hangs at Scanning disk: 00%… I also tried opening the files with Notepad++ but  unsurprisingly, it can't access them.
Do you think it possible to easily recover these files or do I have to look for a better recovery software?
